# Adding a view controller's view as a subview changes it's frame?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, frame, resize

```
    SomeViewController *someVC = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.someViewController = someVC;
    [someVC release];


    NSLog(@"height before added as subview: %f", self.someViewController.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.containerView addSubview:self.someViewController.view];
    NSLog(@"height AFTER added as subview: %f", self.someViewController.view.frame.size.height);

    // height before added as subview: 480.000000
    // height AFTER added as subview: 540.000000
```

What possible explanation is there for this? someViewController's view does not have any autoresizing properties set, and containerView does not autoresize it's subviews. What could cause the frame to change by just adding it as a subview?

A further mystery to this is that it only happens when someViewController's view height is >= 480.

Comment: that is a mystery... what do you get if you replace frame with bounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of view controller is `SomeViewController` ? The one thing I think that may be happening is `SomeViewController` may contain some extra content such as the top bar of an `UINavigationController` and that is automatically increasing the size sometimes. But what you are doing is violating the HIG by adding the view of one view controller to another view controller. An `UIViewController` is designed to be the full view of the screen or belonging to a specialized view controller such as an `UITabBarController`, `UINavigationController`, or `UISplitViewController`. As a result `someViewController` will not function as expected and not receive calls such as `viewDidLoad`. So if you are sure that no autoresizing properties are set all I can recommend is using an `UIView` instead of an `UIViewController`.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. But what prevents viewDidLoad from getting called in the former scenario?

Comment: The reason `viewDidLoad` and other similar methods is not getting called is because those messages are not going to get forwarded to your sub view controller. Apple designed controllers such as the `UINavigationController` to forward all of the appropriate messages to the view controllers so when you attempt to add just the view of a controller to another view that no longer happens.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by the autoresizingMask of the view, it's purpose is to adjust the size to changes in it's super view.